# How to configure the go get command to use http protocol instead of https protocol

Tags: http, gitlab, go-get

The company's private gitlab repository uses the **http** protocol and cannot be pulled through the `go get` command by default.

I setting the `GOPRIVATE` and `GOINSECURE` variables to no avail.

How can I modify it to implement http pull? Looking forward to your reply.

> PS: The `ssh` method cannot be implemented because I use `telnet gitlab.company.com 22` and cannot access it.

Comment: There's a reason why more and more software stops supporting insecure protocols. What I would suggest is to convince people to use https. Its surprising that such companies still exist.

Comment: Because it is an internal system, they do not have https set up

Comment: It doesn't matter whether it is internal or not. Setting up https is simple. What is the reason not to do this?

Comment: Because the private gitlab builder did not configure https, I can't change this situation.